# Masstransit RabbitMQ username password configuration in .Net code

Tags: c#, .net, rabbitmq, masstransit

I am using the recommended approach specified under Masstransit documentation to specify RabbitMQ username and password during bus creation.

Here's the code snippet for bus configuration:

```
var compensateAddress = BuildQueueUri(Settings.BaseUri, Settings.Compensate);
var ExecuteAddress = BuildQueueUri(Settings.BaseUri, Settings.Execute);
var RabbitMqURI = new Uri(Settings.BaseUri + "/QueueName");
var RabbitMqUsername = Settings.RabbitMqUsername;
var RabbitMqPassword = Settings.RabbitMqPassword;

IServiceBus _bus;    

_bus = ServiceBusFactory.New(x =>
            {
                x.UseRabbitMq(r =>
                {
                    r.ConfigureHost(RabbitMqURI, h =>
                    {
                        h.SetUsername(RabbitMqUsername);
                        h.SetPassword(RabbitMqPassword);
                    });
                });                
                x.ReceiveFrom(ExecuteAddress);
                x.Subscribe(s => s.Instance(_host));
            });
```

When I spin up my application, I get the following error:

"the path can be empty, or a sequence of these characters: letters, digits, hyphen, underscore, period, or colon."

What could be the problem?

Masstransit Version 2.9.0

RabbitMQ.Client Version 3.4.0

Comment: What is the value of `ExecuteAddress`?

Comment: I doubt it matters, but in my code I've got the `x.ReceiveFrom(...)` code above the `x.UseRabbitMq` line.  What happens if you try moving it up?

Comment: ExecuteAddress is just a URI of an exchange to publish onto. Also, like you said, moving ReceiveFrom would not change anything.

Comment: I understand it's a URI.  What is the value?

Comment: The reason I ask is I ran into this problem a while back.  MassTransit changed their API sometime ago so you don't specify the username/password in the URI anymore.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18811833/masstransit-rabbit-mq-virtual-host

Comment: Oh sure, I am indeed following the latest approach, not the depricated one from 2.7.0 or whenever it was. 

Here's how I build the URI
In config: <add key="ExecuteQueue" value="Execute_CC_Activity"/>

In a configuration file, I have: 
public static string Execute = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ExecuteQueue"];

So my ExecuteAddess looks like: 
"{rabbitmq://rabbitmqbroker/Execute_CC_Activity}" with other properties set.

Comment: Hm, I dunno then.  We have `String.Format("rabbitmq://{0}/{1}/{2}", Settings.Host, Settings.VirtualHost, queueName);`.  The only thing I see different is you don't have a virtualhost.

Comment: It would really help to see the actual values at run time for each of those variables. Console.WriteLine, and I'm better the answers will be... revealed.

Comment: Forgot the update here but like @ChrisPatterson said, I had incorrect value for BaseURI, where I had "/" in the config and while setting "RabbitMqURI = new Uri(Settings.BaseUri + "/QueueName")", it was getting set to double slashes.

Answer (score 1):

Here is code that I was able to get to work
MT 2.10
Rabbit 3.5.3
Erlang 18.0 64bit

```
 public class YourMessage { public string Text { get; set; } }
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var hostAddress = new Uri("rabbitmq://localhost/learningmt_orderservice");
            Bus.Initialize(sbc =>
            {
                sbc.UseRabbitMq(rabbit =>
                {

                    rabbit.ConfigureHost(hostAddress,
                        chost =>
                        {
                            chost.SetUsername("guest");
                            chost.SetPassword("guest");
                        });
                    rabbit.Validate();
                });

                sbc.ReceiveFrom(hostAddress.AbsoluteUri);
                sbc.Subscribe(subs =>
                {
                    subs.Handler<YourMessage>(msg => Console.WriteLine(msg.Text));
                });
            });

            Bus.Instance.Publish(new YourMessage {Text = "Hi"});
        }
    }
```